# how to use tab in jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I made a webpage and i am supposed to use jquery to put tabs into my page. I am having a problem with it and after numerous attempt to solve it, i failed. The tabs are supposed to link other pages in them.this is the problem i am having.

1. The tab only sticks to my homepage instead of being there in every page.
2. the homepages repeats itself, meaning there are two page one after the other.
3. instead of using id as tb-1, tb-2. i linked the other page into my tab, but it is not working.

below is my partial code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> Underwater World    </title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet"href="ppcss.css">



        <script>

        $(function() {

        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();

        });

        </script>
    </head> 

    <body > 
        <div id="tabs">

        <ul>
        <li><a href="">Homepage</a></li>

        <li><a href="animals.html">Animals</a></li>

        <li><a href="Algae.html">Plants</a></li>

        <li><a href="FAQS.html">F.A.Qs</a></li>

        <li><a href="ContactUs.html">Contact us</a></li>

        </ul>

        <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- header -->
        <div id="header">
        <h1 class="head"> Underwater World </h1>
        <h3 class="subhead">
        A New World!
        </h3>
        </div>


        <!-- left column -->
        <div id="leftcol" >

        <div class="smfeature">
        <h4> Who we are. </h4>
        <p> We are a group of marine biologist that study marine life such as animals, plants and coral reefs. This website will provide you with the most accurate information about the life that lives under the water. </P>
        </div>
```

Comment: if you guys need more code let me know: please help me solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Since you've only added the code to your home page, it will only appear there. jQuery UI tabs are meant to handle content within the same page and rely on IDs and target links to create this functionality. To get your desired results, you would need to bring in the content from each page and place it in a container with an ID and use target links for those IDs. The documentation page gives a great example of it: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#default

Answer (score 0):

First of all, every page is a unique page, in HTML you can't really move a set of elements to other page without using any sort of programming languages like php, etc.

So, you have to write the same block of html elements in every page you make to achieve a similar looking tab structure

If you wish to show the whole page in one HTML page the code can be written as follow:

Fiddle if you wish to see live example http://jsfiddle.net/x2c38smy/

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <ul class="tabs_lists">
        <li><a class="tab_a" rel="home" href="javascript:;">Homepage</a></li>
        <li><a class="tab_a" rel="animals" href="javascript:;">Animals</a></li>
        <li><a class="tab_a" rel="plants" href="javascript:;">Plants</a></li>
        <li><a class="tab_a" rel="faq" href="javascript:;">F.A.Qs</a></li>
        <li><a class="tab_a" rel="contactus" href="javascript:;">Contact us</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="wrapper">      
        <div id="header">
            <h1 class="head">Underwater World</h1>
            <h3 class="subhead">A New World!</h3>
        </div>      
        <div id="leftcol" class="tab_wrapper">
            <div class="smfeature home">
                <h4> Who we are. </h4>
                <p> We are a group of marine biologist that study marine life such as animals, plants and coral reefs. This website will provide you with the most accurate information about the life that lives under the water. </p>
            </div>
            <div class="smfeature animals">
                <h4>Animals</h4>
                <p> We are a group of marine biologist that study marine life such as animals, plants and coral reefs. This website will provide you with the most accurate information about the life that lives under the water. </p>
            </div>
            <div class="smfeature plants">
                <h4>Plants</h4>
                <p> We are a group of marine biologist that study marine life such as animals, plants and coral reefs. This website will provide you with the most accurate information about the life that lives under the water. </p>
            </div>
            <div class="smfeature faq">
                <h4>FAQ's</h4>
                <p> We are a group of marine biologist that study marine life such as animals, plants and coral reefs. This website will provide you with the most accurate information about the life that lives under the water. </p>
            </div>
            <div class="smfeature contactus">
                <h4>Contact Us</h4>
                <p> We are a group of marine biologist that study marine life such as animals, plants and coral reefs. This website will provide you with the most accurate information about the life that lives under the water. </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.smfeature{display:none;}
.smfeature:first-child{display:block;}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tabs_lists .tab_a').click(function(){
        var tab = $(this).attr('rel');
        $('.tab_wrapper div').hide();
        $('.'+tab).show().siblings().hide();
    });
});
```